# How to get the result from insert/update with node-red-node-cf-cloudant

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant, node-red

I'm working with Node-red provided in IBM Bluemix IOT Foundation. It comes with the node-red-node-cf-cloudant package that can easily handle Cloudant DB operations. The Cloudant out node works nicely. What border me is **there is no output from the Cloudant out node** that can tell the flow if the insert/update operation is successful. Now I can only assume it is always successful. Anyone have the same problem as mine? And what is your solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the philosophy is that there is the concept of a `Catch` node that can be added to a flow.  See the `input` category for the node flagged as `catch`.  Reading the documentation for this node, it states that it will be triggered if there is an error thrown by any node on the same tab/page/workflow.  I would assume that if the Cloudant out node is implemented correctly then if it fails, it would thrown some Node-RED formatted error that would cause the `Catch` node to be triggered so you would gain control to perform any error handling, logging or other remediation work that might be applicable.

I am guessing that the Node-RED Github issue that tracked the creation and in which one can read more about the ability can be found here:

https://github.com/node-red/node-red/issues/560

Comment: The cloudant node pre-dates the Catch node, so probably doesn't log the errors in such a way to trigger the Catch node.

Comment: I understand catch node might do the job, but there is quite a lot of limitation, as lots of information are not passed to the catch node. If you need to compose a proper error message back to the user, most likely you need to access the entire msg that passed into the Cloudant node.

Comment: I'm starting to think I can save the error from the Catch node in context objects like flow or global. Then the original path will know if the update is successful by checking the existence of error in the context. Do you think it will work?

Comment: @AlexHui - You bring up an interesting thought.  Personally, I don't think what you are asking will work.  The reason being (and this is a guess) is that an error resulting in a wake up in Catch might very well mean the termination of the original flow and a "goto" to the Catch node.  So although we might be able to set some global context in the Catch node, there might not be "other paths" to sense it.   I'm starting to think that Node-RED might not be what you need... and might want to consider a hand-written JavaScript app.

Comment: Kolban you may be right. I'm going to set up a flow to verify my idea. The reason make me think it might work is you can always branch out the flow from the output of any node. So even the Cloudant out do stop the execution flow on that path, the other branch may still run until the end. Let see what I'll find.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer, though it is not a very useful one.

```
    [
  {
    "id": "a477543c.5b88a8",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "7ac871fa.85379",
    "name": "",
    "active": true,
    "console": "false",
    "complete": "false",
    "x": 293,
    "y": 147,
    "wires": []
  },
  {
    "id": "8c8b0763.7374f8",
    "type": "cloudant out",
    "z": "7ac871fa.85379",
    "service": "your_service",
    "cloudant": "",
    "name": "Save Data",
    "database": "your_db",
    "payonly": true,
    "operation": "insert",
    "x": 292,
    "y": 58,
    "wires": []
  },
  {
    "id": "66f48698.990b78",
    "type": "template",
    "z": "7ac871fa.85379",
    "name": "",
    "field": "payload",
    "fieldType": "msg",
    "format": "json",
    "template": "{\"response\": \"success\"}",
    "x": 669,
    "y": 112,
    "wires": [
      [
        "9fc752f6.6038b"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "9a2f1021.65d0f",
    "type": "catch",
    "z": "7ac871fa.85379",
    "name": "Catch error from Save Data",
    "scope": [
      "8c8b0763.7374f8"
    ],
    "x": 130,
    "y": 207,
    "wires": [
      [
        "41c37106.be3c9",
        "35676738.ca9898",
        "9e4a94f4.61b568"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "41c37106.be3c9",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "7ac871fa.85379",
    "name": "",
    "active": true,
    "console": "true",
    "complete": "true",
    "x": 316,
    "y": 249,
    "wires": []
  },
  {
    "id": "35676738.ca9898",
    "type": "change",
    "z": "7ac871fa.85379",
    "name": "",
    "rules": [
      {
        "t": "set",
        "p": "error",
        "pt": "flow",
        "to": "error",
        "tot": "msg"
      }
    ],
    "action": "",
    "property": "",
    "from": "",
    "to": "",
    "reg": false,
    "x": 330,
    "y": 207,
    "wires": [
      [
        "6c19d8c0.93e628"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "972775b7.68d888",
    "type": "delay",
    "z": "7ac871fa.85379",
    "name": "",
    "pauseType": "delay",
    "timeout": "3",
    "timeoutUnits": "seconds",
    "rate": "1",
    "rateUnits": "second",
    "randomFirst": "1",
    "randomLast": "5",
    "randomUnits": "seconds",
    "drop": false,
    "x": 286,
    "y": 106,
    "wires": [
      [
        "dd0eb63d.22f148"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "dd0eb63d.22f148",
    "type": "switch",
    "z": "7ac871fa.85379",
    "name": "Check flow.error",
    "property": "error",
    "propertyType": "flow",
    "rules": [
      {
        "t": "nnull"
      },
      {
        "t": "else"
      }
    ],
    "checkall": "true",
    "outputs": 2,
    "x": 467,
    "y": 106,
    "wires": [
      [
        "54a9c22f.ab563c"
      ],
      [
        "66f48698.990b78"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "a26776ff.5d9888",
    "type": "template",
    "z": "7ac871fa.85379",
    "name": "",
    "field": "payload",
    "fieldType": "msg",
    "format": "json",
    "template": "{\"response\": {{{payload}}}}\n",
    "x": 975,
    "y": 55,
    "wires": [
      [
        "9fc752f6.6038b"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "54a9c22f.ab563c",
    "type": "change",
    "z": "7ac871fa.85379",
    "name": "",
    "rules": [
      {
        "t": "set",
        "p": "payload",
        "pt": "msg",
        "to": "error",
        "tot": "flow"
      },
      {
        "t": "delete",
        "p": "error",
        "pt": "flow"
      }
    ],
    "action": "",
    "property": "",
    "from": "",
    "to": "",
    "reg": false,
    "x": 687,
    "y": 55,
    "wires": [
      [
        "837ec67c.7c8138"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "6c19d8c0.93e628",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "7ac871fa.85379",
    "name": "",
    "active": true,
    "console": "false",
    "complete": "false",
    "x": 505,
    "y": 207,
    "wires": []
  },
  {
    "id": "433fc13d.bcc04",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "7ac871fa.85379",
    "name": "",
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "{\"_id\":\"0fc076a605741fdffa1580897e1c54a0\",\"message\":\"testing\"}",
    "payloadType": "json",
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": false,
    "x": 120,
    "y": 57,
    "wires": [
      [
        "8c8b0763.7374f8",
        "972775b7.68d888",
        "a477543c.5b88a8"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "9fc752f6.6038b",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "7ac871fa.85379",
    "name": "",
    "active": true,
    "console": "false",
    "complete": "false",
    "x": 1119,
    "y": 108,
    "wires": []
  },
  {
    "id": "9e4a94f4.61b568",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "7ac871fa.85379",
    "name": "",
    "active": true,
    "console": "false",
    "complete": "error",
    "x": 330,
    "y": 297,
    "wires": []
  },
  {
    "id": "837ec67c.7c8138",
    "type": "json",
    "z": "7ac871fa.85379",
    "name": "",
    "x": 843,
    "y": 55,
    "wires": [
      [
        "a26776ff.5d9888"
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

Check this code. I can use a catch node to catch any error thrown from the Cloudant out node and set it to the flow context object. So the original path can check for the existence of the error object in the context after a brief delay. It assume the update is successful if no error found in the context.

However, this is not a useful solution. There will be a concurrency issue when multiple request is received in the same Node-red instance. And there is no session identifier in the error object. There is no way for me to associate the error message with the message that cause the error. Hope someone can figure out a way to improve this solution.